# Generate XML root element with attribute for XML in Spark(scala) using databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to create a nested XML from CSV/DataFrame in scala spark. I am using Databricks spark-XML library for converting the DataFrame to XML format.

I was trying to create an output like below, but unable to achieve it

```
<rows version="1"> 
<row>
<name id=10>Mahashree</name>
</row>
</rows>
```

I have tried with struct

```
{"_VALUE":"Mahashree","@id":10,"__version":1}
```

but resulted as below

```
<rows> 
<row>
<name id=10>Mahashree
<__version>1</__version>
</name>
</row>
</rows>
```

can anyone help to make the attribute in the root element?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share code snippet which you are trying?

Comment: can you share the dataframe and its schema and the code you've tried?